# Converting seconds to hours using dateFormat npm package giving incorrect result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date-format

I wanted to convert `seconds` to `hours` using dateFormat nodejs package but it's not giving expected result.

My code :

```
import dateFormat from 'dateformat';

console.log(dateFormat(3600, "HH"));
```

Result:

when trying to convert `3600 secs` to `hrs` then instead of giving output as `1 hr`, it's giving output as `5 hrs`

Comment: No need to use plugin you can do it using simple javascript check  this code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37096367/how-to-convert-seconds-to-minutes-and-hours-in-javascript

Comment: I answer this question in this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69888278/10871558

Answer (score 0):

dateformat takes first argument as date and not the seconds. If you will convert 3600 to date then it is 52 years ago exact date is `Thursday, 1 January 1970 06:30:00 GMT+05:30` in which hour is 5, which is showing to you. If you need to convert seconds to hours you can use this function

```
function secondsToTime(secs)
{
    var hours = Math.floor(secs / (60 * 60));

    var divisor_for_minutes = secs % (60 * 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor(divisor_for_minutes / 60);

    var divisor_for_seconds = divisor_for_minutes % 60;
    var seconds = Math.ceil(divisor_for_seconds);

    var obj = {
        "h": hours,
        "m": minutes,
        "s": seconds
    };
    return obj;
}
```